# Problem with extrude along the local axis hotkeys

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, extrude, axis

tell me, I'm going through the lesson, the teacher at 2.82 turns out to extrude two faces symmetrically along the local Z axis through E-S-Z-Z, and for some reason, in my case, in 2.92, E-S-Z-Z extrudes along the normals, why, and how to fix it?

Comment: Try S-Z-Z without E, this should work.

Comment: But what I need is a symmetrical extrude along the local axes. I can achieve a similar result from the tutorial through E-esc-G-S-Z-Z, but it's longer and more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you press a key for an axis like <kbd>Z</kbd> multiple times after activating a transformation like *Scale* (<kbd>S</kbd>), it will cycle through a few [Transformation Orientations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html) (*Local, Normal, Global*, ...).

You may have set a different value in the "Transformation Orientations" selection box than in the tutorial. Check the value of this box.

The selection box is located in the top center of the header of the viewport (or at the bottom of the viewport if the header is there). See [screenshot here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html#custom-orientations) in Blender's documentation.